# Правильно ли стоит запятая? "Ты не знаешь(,) когда умрешь."

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли стоит запятая?

"Ты не знаешь(,) когда умрешь."

Имеется ли какое-либо общее правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Ты не знаешь, когда умрешь."* Это СПП: *"Ты не знаешь"* - главное предложение, *"когда умрёшь"* - придаточное предложение. Между главным и придаточным предложениями **положено ставить запятую**.

Правило: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm